# How to generate Windows complete memory dump correctly?

Tags: windows, windbg, dump

Please find the dump sample [on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0J8PsHkLNPcNlhRclpXZU0wUWc/view?usp=sharing) (Complete dump but lack useful info). Platform is Win10 x64 RS2.

I am trying to make a complete memory dump to analyze my app.
I used DumpConfigurator Utility to setup my environment [according to MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2009/07/13/debug-nugget-dumpconfigurator-utility/). I also change the dump key to Ctrl+Space [according to MS Technet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tip_of_the_day/2015/12/08/surface-tip-of-the-day-manually-crash-your-surface-pro-3/)

I am trying to analyze all process' call stack so I need the !process information.

After dump generation, I tried using WinDbg to analyze the process in the dump.
But I cannot get any useful information by `!process` or `!dml_proc`.

It shows:

```
0: kd> !process
Error in reading nt!_EPROCESS at ffffd081a0a56040
0: kd> !dml_proc
ERROR: !dml_proc: extension exception 0x80004005.
"Unable to get type ID of 'nt!_EPROCESS'"
```

I want to ask why this happened and how to generate the dump correctly.

Comment: A minidump is not a process.  If only you had mentioned what kind of info you need.  But alas, somebody is going to have to write a manual.  Give it 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand the difference between a kernel-mode and user-mode memory dump. 
!process can *only* be used on a dump of the entire computer - i.e. a kernel dump. Are you trying to analyze all the threads in a process or all the processes on a system? What information specifically are you looking for?

Comment: I want all informations so I try to generate a complete dump(memory dump type: complete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check and make sure your pagefile is on the same drive as \Windows
  (System Drive) and that it is larger than the size of physical RAM on
  the machine
- If on a different drive, look at the dedicated dump drive
  registry setting to use a different drive for the pagefile (WRT
  memory dumps).
- Ensure that you are using valid MS public symbols

From your memory dump, it looks like it is configured for a complete dump:

**Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Full address space is available**

However based on the output of various commands it looks like the likely culprit is the size of the pagefile or its location (or both). See points referenced above.